# T-SQL Querying a table using a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have been tasked with updating a stored procedure and I'm trying to figure out the most efficient way of performing the select.  Here is the current code, `vaultID` and `clientID` are input parameters:

```
SELECT 
   @siteID = Site.siteID, 
   @siteGroupID = Site.siteGroupID,
   @customerID = Customer.customerID
FROM 
   Customer
INNER JOIN 
   Site ON Customer.siteID = Site.siteID
WHERE 
   Site.phoneNumberIVR = @vaultID 
   AND Site.production = 1
   AND Customer.clientID = @clientID
```

The update I'm working on has to do with the `@clientID` variable. If a record has a specific `@siteGroupID`, the `clientID` needs to be passed in as it was received. If the record has a different type of `@siteGroupID`, the `@clientID` variable needs to be appended with a specific prefix. That prefix is also going to be stored on the site table.

I realize I can make a call to the site table initially to get the prefix, and then modify the `@clientID` variable, but I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to do this with just one call. I've been trying different case statements but I'm not sure this is even feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly, then you should be able to throw a `CASE` in your `SELECT` with your condition to do the appending:

```
SELECT 
    @siteID = Site.siteID, 
    @siteGroupID = Site.siteGroupID,
    @customerID = Customer.customerID,
    @clientID = 
        CASE
            WHEN Site.siteGroupID = 1234 THEN Site.Prefix + @clientID
            ELSE @clientID
        END
FROM 
    Customer
    inner join Site on Customer.siteID = Site.siteID
WHERE 
    Site.phoneNumberIVR = @vaultID 
    and Site.production = 1
    and Customer.clientID = @clientID
```

Of course, depending on the datatypes of `@clientID` and `Site.Prefix`, you might have to do something other than a simple `+` to do the appending. For example if both were `integer` datatypes, you can append then with some `CONVERT` calls:

```sql
@clientID = CONVERT(integer, CONVERT(varchar, Site.Prefix) + CONVERT(varchar, @clientID))
```

Comment: Thank you!!!!  I was actually fairly close but had an equals sign in there that was blowing it up.  Thanks for the quick response